# Append Columns via List of Column/Value Pairs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` with columns `A` and `B`:

```
A       |     B
---------------
1       |     2
4       |     3
```

I want to apply a function `getData` that gets `A` and returns a list of tuples (column / value pairs):

Example, for the first row:

```
[('C', 5), ('D', 1), ('Z', 1)]
```

and for the second row:

```
[('E', 5), ('Z', 3)]
```

I'm aiming for a resulting dataframe that looks like this (with missing values replaced):

```
A       |     B    |     C    |     D   |     E    |     Z
----------------------------------------------------------
1       |     2    |     5    |     1   |     0    |     1
4       |     3    |     0    |     0   |     5    |     3
```

Is there any short / easy solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert key-values to `dict` and then to `Series` if is possible modify function:

```
def getData(x):
    if x == 1:
        a = [('C', 5), ('D', 1), ('Z', 1)]
    else:
        a = [('E', 5), ('Z', 3)]

    return (pd.Series(dict(a)))

df1 = df['A'].apply(getData)
print (df1)
     C    D    E    Z
0  5.0  1.0  NaN  1.0
1  NaN  NaN  5.0  3.0
```

Or use list comprehension with `DataFrame` constructor:

```
s = df['A'].apply(getData)
print (s)
0    [(C, 5), (D, 1), (Z, 1)]
1            [(E, 5), (Z, 3)]
Name: A, dtype: object

df1 = pd.DataFrame([dict(x) for x in s])
print (df1)

     C    D    E  Z
0  5.0  1.0  NaN  1
1  NaN  NaN  5.0  3
```

And last `join` original, remove `NaN` and convert to `int`:

```
df1 = df.join(df1).fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df1)
   A  B  C  D  E  Z
0  1  2  5  1  0  1
1  4  3  0  0  5  3
```

EDIT:

Numpy [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42340769/2901002):

```
df['A'] = df['A'].apply(getData)
print (df)
                          A  B
0  [(C, 5), (D, 1), (Z, 1)]  2
1          [(E, 5), (Z, 3)]  3

tid1 = df.index
lens = [len(i) for i in df['A'].values]
tid2 = tid1.repeat(lens)
cat, prob = np.concatenate(df['A'].values).T
ucat, inv = np.unique(cat, return_inverse=True)
data = np.zeros((len(tid1), len(ucat)), dtype=float)
data[tid2, inv] = prob
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, tid1, ucat)
print (df1)
     C    D    E    Z
0  5.0  1.0  0.0  1.0
1  0.0  0.0  5.0  3.0
```

Comment: ``df1 = pd.DataFrame([dict(x) for x in s])`` - This step gives me a ``MemoryError``. But ``s.memory_usage(deep = True)`` returns 47,446,392 which seems to be an acceptable number.

Comment: Hmmmm, so DataFrame is very large? What is number of rows?

Comment: It has 11,590 rows, and the resulting DataFrame will have more than 10,000 columns.

Comment: Hmmm, it is not so large. I add another solution, give me some time.